# What is use of map.remove() in get method of following LRU implementation?

Tags: java, lru

I am studying LRU and using below code snippet for understanding it's implementation. Please let me know what is use of `map.remove(key)` method call in `get(int key)`. Can't we just use `map.put(key,value)`, which will update entry in map for the key.
 I am refeing below code .

```
class LRUMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V>{
    private final int MAX_NUM;
    public LRUMap(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
        MAX_NUM = capacity;
    }
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
       return /*true*/ size() > MAX_NUM;
    }
}
public class LRU {
    LRUMap<Integer, Integer> map;
    public LRU(int capacity) {
        map = new LRUMap<Integer, Integer>(capacity);
    }
    public int get(int key) {
        if (map == null || map.get(key) == null)
           return -1;
        int value = map.get(key);
        map.remove(key);
        map.put(key, value);
        return value;
    }
    public void set(int key, int value) {
        if (map == null) return;
        get(key);
        map.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your code, or where is it coming from?

Comment: @ghostCat No this is not my code

Comment: @GhostCat it does not matter, it's pretty simple, actually

Comment: @Eugene The point is: when that is some library somewhere, then it might be helpful to look at the corresponding Javadoc for example. Which is easier to find when you have more details.

Comment: Ok, to be more precise: where is it coming from then? I only find an apache LRUMap class, and that doesn't look like what you are showing here.

Comment: @GhostCat javadoc has nothing to do with it, it's an implementation detail, actually it's a detail that makes it work correctly, not sure this counts as a detail per-se

Comment: if you were to use [`super(capacity, 0.75f, true);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap-int-float-boolean-) you'd have a map with automatic access order and you could get rid of most code in the `LRU` class (e.g. just `return map.getOrDefault(key, -1);` for `get`)

Comment: @zapl indeed, that’s horrible code. Besides the fact that `LinkedHashMap` already supports access order, the two `get` operations are obsolete when the subsequent `remove` returns the old value anyway and the `set` method is maxing it out by calling the `get` method first, ending up making five hash lookups for a single operation. Plus these obsolete `null` checks…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This `LRUMap` extends `LinkedHashMap`, which maintains a linked list of the entries of the `Map` in the order the keys were inserted (the first key being the first key added to the `Map`).

When you implement a least recently used data structure, you want to know which element was least recently used. That's the element you'll remove first when you run out of space.

Now, if we look at the `LinkedHashMap` Javadoc:

> This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). **Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map. (A key k is reinserted into a map m if m.put(k, v) is invoked when m.containsKey(k) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)**

We see that calling `put(k,v)` for a key already present in the `Map` doesn't affect the insertion order.

Therefore, when you access a key of the `Map`, you have to first remove it from the `LinkedHashMap` and then re-add it, thus moving it to the end of the linked list, and effectively marking it as the most recently used key (which is the last inserted key).

Note that the `set()` method also calls `get()`, which means it also moves the key to the end of the linked list if it was already in the `Map`.

Comment: But it should be noted that using [the constructor specifically made to allow to enable access-order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api//java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap-int-float-boolean-) would be much simpler and cleaner than this remove-and-re-insert kludge…

Answer (score 4):

LRU = Least *recently* used cache.

When you use a `Key` it should become the most recently used. Simply updating it would not make it the most *recently* used since it doesn't change the index in the underlying `LinkedList`.
Thus `remove` and put it back. This way it does becomes the most recent one.